# I'd like to count number of work items with linked test cases in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard that will let me monitor the "health" of the system being developed.

One of the parameters I'd like to measure is whether relevant work items have been linked to test cases.
I would like to display this as numbered "Query tiles" on the dashboard.
I have succeeded fine in the query that finds work items (in this case Ændringsønsker) that are **not** linked to a test case ([screenshot of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AVmm.png)) by using "work items and direct links" and selecting "Only return items that do not have matching links" and checking the "Tested by" box.
This give me a flat list and the counter is just fine.

When I perform the same query, but selecting "Only return items that have matching links" I get all the work items intended, but I also get all of the linked items in the hierarchy. This screws up my counter as all test cases are also counted.

Any ideas as to how I can get rid of the excess items (test cases)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, the tiles don't support that.  I would recommend you try the marketplace extension [Query Tile PRO](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mskold.mskold-Query-Tile-PRO) which allows you to use the linked query but only do the counts on either parent or child.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my issue completely. And made it possible for me to do other stuff I've been struggling with for a while.